# Armv6 Assembler for Mac

Tags: macos, assembly, operating-system, kernel, raspberry-pi

I am following this tutorial on operating system development for the raspberry pi.
http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/ok01.html

I am using a Mac, so it suggests using the Yagarto packages for assembling the code.  However, they do not seem to work.  I installed it multiple times to check.

I want to know if there is an alternative assembler for Mac and how to use it to create the .img file to use as the kernel for the pi.

Comment: there are a number of pre-builts out there.  by far the simplest thing is to have a second raspberry pi and just develop natively on that it already has an arm assembler.  or use a virtual machine on your mac and either run an arm linux and use the native toolchain or otherwise run linux on the virtual machine and on that build or get a binutils for arm, it is very easy to build on linux.  Maybe it is as easy to build on mac.

Comment: `/usr/bin/as -arch armv6 main.s`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Xcode for that - if you install xcode, the "iPhone SDK" compiler is really a cross compiler for i386, x86_64 and - ARM.

```
${whereever_you_put_xcode}/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/as -arch armv6
```

will do the trick: specifically, it will execute

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/../libexec/as/arm/as`

Comment: It actually looks like you can just run `as -arch armv6 main.s` and get the same output file. There's an `as` at /usr/bin/as, which doesn't appear to be symlinked to anything else (Mountain Lion).